# Docker CE installation issue: Invalid configuration of SYS_GID_MIN, GID_MIN, or SYS_GID_MAX

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, docker

I run Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS and I am trying to install Docker CE.

I followed the official Docker CE [installation instructions](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-docker-ce):

```bsh
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
sudo add-apt-repository \
    "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
    $(lsb_release -cs) \
    stable"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
```

The last command failed with the following message:

```
...
Setting up docker-ce (5:18.09.1~3-0~ubuntu-xenial) ...
groupadd: Invalid configuration: SYS_GID_MIN (101), GID_MIN (100), SYS_GID_MAX (99)
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 4
...
```

How to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this discussion](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/23365#issuecomment-224638271), the issue seems to be with the configuration specified in the `/etc/login.defs` file. I uncommented the following line

```
#SYS_GID_MAX          999
```

and the installation succeeded.